# Does the Nuka-Cola bottler actually generate nuka cola?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, when you reach 100 dwellers you unlock the Nuka-Cola bottler. the description says:

> ASSIGN DWELLERS HERE TO PRODUCE NUKA-COLA!

But after I built it, I seem to only be getting food and water. I've had it for quite some time without getting any Nuka-Cola, and was wondering if it actually produces it. And if it does, is there a way to increase the chances?

Comment: In the real world, bottlers only add (carbonated) water and put it in bottles and cans. They are adding it to syrup they receive from the manufacturer. Works a lot like SodaStream...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it only produces food and water. [Source](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Nuka-Cola_bottler)

[image: Screenshot from Fandom]

Comment: That's a shame. But thank you for the answer! Cheers :)

Comment: It's not a shame; it's a sham. If it did there'd be *absolutely* no reason to micro-purchase something that you **can use cheats to get**.